# Why doesn't Chrome/Chromium and Android require API authorization

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0, authorization

Chromium and Android are both open source programs which means that they can be modified (maliciously). In both Android x86 and Chromium it doesn't ask for API authorization unlike other apps that sign in with Google. I am thinking why it doesn't and if it is a security breach.

Comment: What's API authorization?

Comment: @tinysunlight Other apps that sign in with Google have an allow button.Chromium/Android does not

Comment: Because it's product of Google.

Comment: @tinysunlight But anyone can modify them for malicous purposes

Comment: What's the malicous purposes?I think API authorization is just for account check.

Comment: @tinysunlight Delete account data and look at documents

Answer (score 0):

API doesn't need authorization as they are already signed by a certificate. When a user installed an android app, it is assumed that he has given authorization for all api that comes with it for execution. 
Regarding modification, no one else can modifiy and repackage the app, unless it has the same certificate as the app developer had, which he has to mandatorily sign the app when release the app.
read this : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Then why does Android x86 not require authorization

Comment: I am not talking about Android apps